# Reactive Extensions: Converting a synchronous subscription to asynchronous

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

I have synchronous subscriptions to a sequence of observable data implemented similarly to this piece of code:

```
integers.Where(id => (id & 1) == 0).Subscribe(id => evenHandler.LRP(id, RandomDelay()));
integers.Where(id => (id & 1) == 1).Subscribe(id => oddHandler.LRP(id, RandomDelay()));
```

The problem is the operations are blocking, so you end with a scenario like this:

```
OddHandler running with ID 1 for 331ms...
EvenHandler running with ID 2 for 651ms...
OddHandler running with ID 3 for 391ms...
EvenHandler running with ID 4 for 633ms...
OddHandler running with ID 5 for 197ms...
```

I want to operations to run asynchronously and I don't have access to the `IHandler` interface that exposes the method `LRP`.  After doing some research, it appears there are at least two ways to do this using RX:

Method 1:

```
integers.Where(id => (id & 1) == 0)
    .Select(async id => await Task.Run(() => evenHandler.LRP(id, RandomDelay())))
    .Subscribe();

integers.Where(id => (id & 1) == 1)
    .Select(async id => await Task.Run(() => oddHandler.LRP(id, RandomDelay())))
    .Subscribe();
```

Method 2:

```
integers.Where(id => (id & 1) == 0)
    .SelectMany(id => Observable.StartAsync(
        async () => await Task.Run(() => evenHandler.LRP(id, RandomDelay())))
    ).Subscribe();

integers.Where(id => (id & 1) == 1)
    .SelectMany(id => Observable.StartAsync(
        async () => await Task.Run(() => oddHandler.LRP(id, RandomDelay())))
    ).Subscribe();
```

Both methods *appear* to generate the same result.

My questions:

1. What are the differences between the two techniques?
2. What is the recommended way of accomplishing what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stay away from *Method 1*, as it "breaks" Rx a bit. When you `await` inside the `Select` you're making what's a synchronous operator do asynchronous work. Whenever you want to do something asynchronous, put it inside a `SelectMany`. `SelectMany` even accepts a `Task<T>` directly.

In *Method 2* you're wrapping the `Task` inside an observable. I believe this is very similar to `Observable.FromAsync()`. However it's a bit heavy handed creating a `Task` and then converting it to an observable; you could just use an observable directly:

```
integers.Where(id => (id & 1) == 0)
    .SelectMany(id => Observable.Start(
        () => evenHandler.LRP(id, RandomDelay()),
        ThreadPoolScheduler.Default))
    .Subscribe();

integers.Where(id => (id & 1) == 1)
    .SelectMany(id => Observable.Start(
        () => oddHandler.LRP(id, RandomDelay()),
        ThreadPoolScheduler.Default))
    .Subscribe();
```

This will create an observable that returns a `Unit` when the inner work is done. I've also specified that it should run on the `TaskPoolScheduler` which makes it run inside a `Task`.